# Odoo How Can I update my value from another module's value

Tags: odoo

I have a question...

As you know in odoo we have sales and purchase apps. I am building a module which will be
provide update product prices in the sales module from the vendor price  in the purchase app.

I created a wizard and linked to purchase app.

[image]

Okay here is my question...

I want to do this simply.

```
product.supplierinfo.["price"] = product.product_template["list_price"]
```

I tried:

```
for rec self.env["product.supplierinfo"]:

    self.env[product.product_template["list_price"]] = rec.["price"]
```

But as you know it's not working ^^

Any advice for this?

Comment: Can you describe the "x price will be updated to y price" in bit more detail? What price and where will be updated by what price from where?

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean to do like this

```
new_price= self.env[product.product_template].write({
    "list_price" : rec.price,
})
```